# send array of ids checkbox in JS to route symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony

I seek how to send a picture ids to the route with javaScript?
I beginner in JS :(

For example if I tick checkbox 2 then I chose one action (delete users) from the menu. So 2 users will be deleted with the page refresh. and if I select all and I chose the action (delete users) are therefore deleted.

here the code of menu:

```
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="{{ path('ben_new_user') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> add user</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="js-enable" data-action="1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> Active</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="js-enable" data-action="0"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Desable</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="js-promote" data-action="USER"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Promote to user</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="js-promote" data-action="MANAGER"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Promote to manager</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="js-promote" data-action="ADMIN"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Promote to Admin</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
```

here the code of button checkbox:

```
  <input id="checkall" type="checkbox" value=""> // for select all users
      {% for entity in entity %}
   <input  type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="{{ entity.id }}">
     {% endfor %}
```

Code in JS;

```
 $("#checkall").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

 </script>
```

thank you for helping me to make this helped in JS

Comment: you don't need javascript to do that, but if you want to do it using javascript you might as well update the data with an ajax call instead of page refresh.

 use fos js routing to communicate with your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this code that I put in the subject but to select all checkbox without recovery ids to send to the road "delete_users".

thank you for helping me,